# Node.JS getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND on hundreds of simultaneous requests

Tags: node.js, https, request, axios, unirest

When I need to make several hundreds of simultaneous requests, Node.JS gives me this error. I tried making the requests with Axios, Unirest, Node.JS request library, and Node.JS HTTPS library.

The specific error (it always is the same) is the one below:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <server> <server>:443
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
```

Weirdly, it only happens maybe on the fith to tenth request (the whole rest resolve and work properly, even the first four ones).

Any clues? Any way to make Node.JS cache the DNS queries, at least, for a few seconds?

Comment: One guess is that this is your DNS requests timing out due to the high number of simultaneous requests. Can you tried throttling/debouncing requests, e.g. with lodash?
See
+ https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/
+ https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce
+ https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#throttle

Comment: @AndreasPizsa the thing was to optimize this to be run in the least time possible. It does need to be fast. I finally decided to do this via the server's IP.

Comment: @Kyngo I'm facing a very similar issue here. Did you end up fixing it?

Comment: @HaoChang I wish, but nope.